# Sustituir palabra con Char array

Tags: java, array, char

Solo lo hago como practica, pero tengo el problema con el iterador, ya que si no coloco la **sentencia if**, me salta **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4**
Les agradeceria que me ayudaran.

```
char txtArray[] = txt.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
char palabraArray[] = palabra.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
char reemplazoArray[] = reemplazo.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        
//buscarPalabra es un metodo que devuelve el primer indice donde se encontro la palabra
//Se puede sustituir ingresando directamente las posiciones de la palabra
List<Integer> indices = buscarPalabra(txt, palabra);
        
List<Character> txtCorregido = new ArrayList<>();


int i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < txtArray.length) {
    if (i == indices.get(j)) {
        for (int k = 0; k < reemplazoArray.length; k++) {
            txtCorregido.add(reemplazoArray[k]); //Escribe el reemplazo
        }
        i = i + palabraArray.length; //Avanza hasta la posicion donde acaba la palabra a reemplazar
        if (j < indices.size() - 1) { //Tuve que poner esto para que funcione
            j++; //Avanza en el indice
        }
    } else {
        txtCorregido.add(txtArray[i]); //Copia el texto original
        i++; //Avanza en el texto
    }
}

String cadena = "";
for (Character character : txtCorregido) {
    cadena = cadena + character;
}
System.out.println(cadena);
```

Comment: *Index 4 out of bounds for length 4* -> Es obvio, en programación (de hecho *casi* en todos los lenguajes) los índices empiezan en 0... con lo cual si tienes longitud 4, tu límite es 3: `0, 1, 2, 3` son 4 índices! Tú estás intentando acceder al índice `4`... eso sería longitud 5. Cuando hagas este tipo de accesos, siempre debes usar `length - 1` como límite superior, o en este caso al sumar las longitudes a tu índice actual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el método contiene un sutil error, cuando avanzas en contador lo haces con:

```
i = i + palabraArray.length;
```

A simple vista parece correcto, pero no lo es, es muy muy fácil equivocarse con la lógica de estos procedimientos, la forma correcta de pensarlo, es la siguiente:
tenemos lo que yo llamo una condición de avance (esta nos dice cuantos espacios tenemos que avanzar dentro del array), y estamos dentro de un iterador, este por su naturaleza, automáticamente nos va a avanzar una posición, por lo tanto, siempre debemos usar "condición -1", en este caso, la condición es el largo de la palabra, por eso debemos usar:

```
i = i + palabraArray.length -1;
```

Es por eso, que el agregado del "if" lo arregla.

En un supuesto caso, en que la palabra a reemplazar y la reemplazada tengan distinta longitud, siempre se debe usar la longitud de la palabra reemplazada.
Para que quede claro porque es la forma correcta de pensarlo, pensemos en el siguiente escenario, "reemplazar 'a' por 'e', pero solo si no existe una 'a' en las tres posiciones anteriores, aca nos encontramos con que la longitud de la palabra es "1", y las condición es "3", si usaramos "longitud de palabra -1", el método fallaría.

lamento llegar tarde...

Comment: *notarás que ya estás en la posición (i)* -> No tiene absolutamente nada que ver en qué posición estás... puedes estar en la posición 0 aún que si le sumas la longitud entera de un string, siempre vas a pasarte. Por qué? PORQUE LOS ÍNDICES EMPIEZAN EN 0 NO EN 1!! El límite de índices de acceso a cualquier conjunto de datos en programación **siempre** es `longitud - 1` (excepto en casos muy puntuales donde los índices empiezan en 1, pero es raro que eso sea así)

Comment: Obviamente lo expresé pesimamente...